# left Join query in access 2013

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am new to Microsoft Access. Accept my apology if my question seems trivial.

I am trying to write a query in Access that shows the total number of students enrolled in  courses on a monthly basis. I have two tables named `course` and `confirmed_enrollments`.

The `course` table has only one field named `course_name` whereas the `confirmed_enrolments` table has three fields; `student_code`, `course_name`, and `month_of_enrol`.

I want to show **all** `course_name` *(whether students enrolled in it or not)* in my query and their total enrollments of the particular month. The query I have written only shows the courses that have enrollment and does not consider the courses which does not have enrollment.

Looking for your help. Here is my SQL code:

```
SELECT Course.Course_name, 
        Count(confirmed_enrolments.Student_code) AS CountOfStudent_code,
        confirmed_enrolments.Month_of_enrol
    FROM Course 
         LEFT JOIN confirmed_enrolments 
             ON Course.Course_name = confirmed_enrolments.Course_name
    GROUP BY Course.Course_name, confirmed_enrolments.Month_of_enrol
    HAVING confirmed_enrolments.Month_of_enrol="December 2016";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you intend this:

```
SELECT c.Course_name, Count(ce.Student_code) AS CountOfStudent_code, 
       ce.Month_of_enrol
FROM Course as c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT ce.*
      FROM confirmed_enrolments as ce
      WHERE ce.Month_of_enrol = "December 2016"
     ) as ce
     ON c.Course_name = ce.Course_name
GROUP BY c.Course_name, ce.Month_of_enrol;
```

The use of the `HAVING` clause in your query is clever, but you are filtering by the second table -- and the value is `NULL` rather than the specified month -- when there are no matches.

The issue is that the condition is on the *second* table.  In a normal SQL dialect, you would write:

```
SELECT c.Course_name, Count(ce.Student_code) AS CountOfStudent_code, 
       ce.Month_of_enrol
FROM Course as c LEFT JOIN
     confirmed_enrolments as ce
     ON c.Course_name = ce.Course_name AND
        ce.Month_of_enrol = "December 2016"
GROUP BY c.Course_name, ce.Month_of_enrol;
```

But MS Access doesn't seem to allow the second comparison in a `LEFT JOIN`.

By the way, another way to write the query uses a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT c.Course_name,
       (SELECDT Count(ce.*) 
        FROM confirmed_enrolments as ce
        WHERE ce.Month_of_enrol = "December 2016"
       ) AS CountOfStudent_code, 
       "December 2016" as ce.Month_of_enrol
FROM Course as c ;
```